# Trying to get div to stick at the top while scrolling a page. It is staying at the top but the CSS is getting deformed

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a type of search box div for my site that I want to stick to the top when the user scrolls down to look at the data. Though when I scroll down, the div stays at the top, but everything gets deformed.

**EDIT:** I am not using any extra CSS for the divs. It is a Bootstrap container class div inside a jumbotron class div.

[Here is what it ends up looking like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC5Lg.jpg)

```
    <div class="container" id="searcher" style="text-align: center;">
        <h2>Where Do You Want To Go?</h2>
        <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control"></input>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="pType" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Select Permit Type
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Every Type</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Commuter Zone A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Commuter Zone B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Commuter Zone C</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Commuter Zone D</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Commuter Zone L</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Night Commuter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resident Permits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newark and Camden Permits (L)</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The code I'm using:

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#searcher');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100)
        $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '10px'});
    else
        $cache.css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto'});
}
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
fixDiv();
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant CSS-code?

Comment: There really isn't any other CSS for that. It is just a Bootstrap container class div inside a jumbotron class div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see your CSS. I'm pretty sure your fixed element would need some different styling added as fixed elements aren't in the flow of the document, they aren't going to "fit their parent" and other oddities.

Additionally, rather than style the menu via javascript, consider adding/removing a class in the function. Then you can just make a different CSS class that styles the menu AND  you can debug your menu just by adding the class and refreshing the page.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100)
    $cache.addClass('fixedMenu');
else
    $cache.removeClass('fixedMenu');
```

Then add some css like:

```
#searcher.fixedMenu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    etc...
}
```

Comment: There really isn't any other CSS for that. It is just a Bootstrap container class div inside a jumbotron class div.

Comment: I know, but what I am saying is that most likely you will need some other CSS for when the div is fixed. Note the fixed div will not act like it's inside another div when it becomes fixed. Items you might think will inherit won't.

Comment: As a hunch try to increase the width of the div when fixed and see what results you get as it looks like the menu is only as wide as some of the text.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm guessing I would have to somehow overwrite the container divs id when it's position is fixed.

I'm a Java developer going into web design so I'm slowly learning CSS.

Comment: That's why I'm saying add a unique class, I'll edit to show you what I mean.

Comment: Now comes to fun part of making the CSS work. Thanks!

Comment: That's always the fun part. Positioning is one of those things in CSS that never gets "easy".